# JSDoc links to callback function

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsdoc

I have decided to use JSDoc to document a project I am working on. While reading the usage guide and questions here I still feel that I am not grasping some of the core concepts of JSDoc and I illustrated my incompetence in the following example: http://jsfiddle.net/zsbtykpv/

```
/**
 * @module testModule
 */

/**
 * @constructor
 */
var Test = function() {
    /**
     * @callback myCallback
     * @param {Object} data An object that contains important data.
     */

    /**
     * A method that does something async
     * @param  {myCallback} cb a callback function
     * @return {boolean} always returns true
     */
    this.method = function(cb) {
        doSomethingAsync(function(data) {
            cb(data);
        });
        return true;
    }

}

module.exports = Test;
```

Here, I have defined a module, indicated a constructor, and documented a method that takes a callback as one of its' parameters. Sounds pretty simple and appears to follow the guidelines set by the usage guide http://usejsdoc.org/.

But for some reason beyond my understanding (and that's probably the core concept I'm not getting), it shows the callback myCallback as a member of the testModule instead of the Test class. Shouldn't it default to be a member of the class and not the module? This also appears to prevent JSDoc from making a link to the callback definition, which is not a lot of fun.

Now I realize that if I were to write:

```
/**
 * @callback module:testModule~Test~myCallback
 * @param {Object} data An object that contains important data.
 */

/**
 * A method that does something async
 * @param  {module:testModule~Test~myCallback} cb a callback function
 * @return {boolean} always returns true
 */
```

I would get my desired behavior. But this seems to be a very clunky way of doing things and the generated links are far from pretty.

Sorry for the long buildup and thank you in advance for your help in my documentation effort :)

Answer (score 0):

I have come across much the same problem. If you want nicer-looking links, you can always add a `{@link}` in the description and just use the canonical name in the `@type` like this:

```
/**
 * @callback module:testModule~Test~myCallback
 * @param {Object} data An object that contains important data.
 */

/**
 * @param {myCallback} cb {@link module:testModule~Test~myCallback|myCallback}: a callback function
 * @return {boolean} always returns true
 */
```

I realize that's a bit more frustrating to type, but it documents `myCallback` as a member of the class rather than the module, and the link looks nice.

If you really want the link in the `@type` and you don't care about how it documents the callback, you could also do this, which is a little less verbose (and what I've decided to do for my project):

```
/**
 * @callback myCallback
 * @param {Object} data An object that contains important data.
 */

/**
 * @param {module:testModule~myCallback} cb a callback function
 * @return {boolean} always returns true
 */
```

That will properly link to `myCallback` and document it as a member of the module.